# VBS split a comma delimited line in a textfile

Tags: vbscript, split

I am not a vbs scripting guy but need to solve a problem with a comma delimited line in a textfile that i would like to split up in separate files, i can split the line into multiple files but all the files ens up containing all split lines, so somehow i get it wrong.

Current script is like this

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set src = fso.OpenTextFile("c:\Temp\Read.txt",1)
lines = split(src.readall, ",")

for i = 1 to ubound(lines)
set dst = fso.CreateTextFile( i & ".txt", true)
dst.writeline lines(0)
dst.writeline lines(1)
dst.writeline lines(2)
dst.writeline lines(3)
dst.writeline lines(4)
dst.writeline lines(5)

dst.close
next
```

Read.txt looks like this.

```
c:\Folder1\.\\, D:\Folder1\.\\, D:\Folder2\.\\
```

The textline sometimes include one folder and sometimes it is 6 or 7 folders so the line contains any number from 1 to 10 commadelimited folderpaths. there is only one line in the file.

i would like the output to be a new textfile for each split and that the space is removed to, as the ending ".\\" (remove last three characters)
I know how to do parts of it in a separate vbs but have no clue how to include it in the same script as above., below is the ending output i would like to get.

1.txt *containing*

```
C:\Folder1\
```

2.txt *containing*

```
D:\Folder1\
```

3.txt *containing*

```
D:\Folder2\
```

etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use .ReadLine() on the input file ('there is only one line in the file') - to get rid of a possible EOL automagically
2. Split on the 'real' separator ", " (not ",")
3. VBScript loop counters start at 0
4. Use anonymous textstream objects - no extra variable, no close needed
5. Think twice before you ask me about goFS and qq()

In code:

```
  Dim aParts : aParts = Split(goFS.OpenTextFile("..\testdata\22879679\22879679.txt").ReadLine(), ", ")
  WScript.Echo Join(aParts)
  Dim nF
  For nF = 0 To UBound(aParts)
      goFS.CreateTextFile("..\testdata\22879679\" & (NF + 1) &".txt").WriteLine aParts(nF)
  Next
  For nF = 0 To UBound(aParts)
      WScript.Echo qq(goFS.OpenTextFile("..\testdata\22879679\" & (NF + 1) &".txt").ReadAll())
  Next
```

output:

```
c:\Folder1\.\\ D:\Folder1\.\\ D:\Folder2\.\\
"c:\Folder1\.\\
"
"D:\Folder1\.\\
"
"D:\Folder2\.\\
"
```

Comment: Looks good, Ekkehard. Except I don't believe he wants the .\\ written to the file. Since the .\\ seems useless (and needs to be removed anyway), we could also do something like this when creating our initial array: `aParts = Split(Replace(goFS.OpenTextFile("..\testdata\22879679\22879679.txt").ReadLine(), ".\\", ""), ", ")` and then we don't have to worry about them later on.

Comment: I got the goFs, but qq didnt make sense to me, i removed qq and script run as expected. Anyway i would like to know the purpose off qq. Thank you for the help guys!

Comment: Looks like Ekkehard was just using it to put quotes around the output (qq = double quotes).

Answer (score 0):

Just want to share the final script

```
Option Explicit
Dim goFS  : Set goFS  = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" )
Dim aParts : aParts = split(Replace(goFS.OpenTextFile("..\folder\read.txt").ReadLine(), ".\\", ""), ", ")
Dim nF
For nF = 0 To UBound(aParts)
goFS.CreateTextFile("..\folder\" & (NF + 1) &".txt").WriteLine aParts(nF)
Next
For nF = 0 To UBound(aParts)
WScript.Echo (goFS.OpenTextFile("..\folder\" & (NF + 1) &".txt").ReadAll())
Next
```

Answer (score -1):

```
varTime=FormatDateTime (Now, 3)
varMode=Right(varTime, 2)
varNewLength=Len(varTime)-3
varTime=Left(varTime, varNewLength)
TestString = varTime
TestArray = Split(varTime , ":")

strHR=TestArray(0)
print strHR 
strMN=TestArray(1)
print strMN
strSC=TestArray(2)
print strSC

If varMode="PM" Then
strHR=strHR+12  
End If

varTime=strHR&":"&strMN&":"&strSC
```

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer by explaining how your code solves the problem. Providing a block of code with no explanation is often unhelpful.